# Sass:math module is not loading

Tags: sass

While i was trying to @use "sass:math"; module in scss file this was not working. This shows some error.I belive i donot have the access for build in module. I attached some screenshots. At that moment i need some help for solving this dilemma.Also that syntax was not highlighting.
First image:[not highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT4ty.jpg)
Second image:[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5SWC.jpg)

note- my sass verstion is Ruby Sass 3.7.4

I need a solution as fast as possible.

Comment: As an aside, Ruby Sass is depreciated. Get Dart Sass

Comment: thank you for the advise My problem is solved for now .